# WPF Form and User Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF form with a left and right dock panels. The left panel has some user inputs based on which I create and launch different user controls within the right dock panel. We are using MMVM framework. Currently, we are creating and launching the user controls from the View Model of the form. I am not sure if this is correct as it appears to violate the MVVM rule of VM should not access View. Is that correct? Is there an alternative design that I could use (I guess I cannot write anything in the code-behind also, correct?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You shouldn't be having any View specific code in the ViewModel. You *can* have code-behind if it is purely UI (no business logic) related.

There is a great article on MSDN on MVVM [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). I suggest, you read this article before writing any WPF applications using MVVM pattern.

For your specific scenario, I would have `ContentControl` in the right hand side panel and have separate `ViewModel`s to back different `UserControl`s and then have `DataTemplates` defined to display the right `UserControl` for any given `ViewModel`s.

Untested Pseudo Code:

**DataTemplates**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
   <local:UserControl1 />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
   <local:UserControl2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

You would define those in `Window.Resources` section or in a `ResourceDictionary` and include that dictionary in `Window.Resources`

**ContentControl**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" />
```

In your current ViewModel that is backing the MainWindow, you will have a property called `CurrentContent`, and when you set it to the right ViewModel instance, the appropriate and associated `View/UserControl` will appear on the screen.

**UPDATE**

You will have `TabControl` instead of a `ContentControl` and have an `ObservableCollection` property (let's say it is named as `ContentItems`) in your ViewModel instead of CurrentContent. `TabControl` will add/remove `TabItems` as you add/remove items to/from the `ObservableCollection`.

```
   <TabControl ItemsSrouce="{Binding ContentItems}" />
```

I am pasting sample TabControl code from one of my projects.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
            Margin="5"
            Visibility="{Binding HasTabs, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Header}"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It makes much more sense and looks cleaner. 
What if I want to load multiple user controls simulataneously (maybe in different tabs, creating a new one as required)? I am guessing the structure would change, but not entirely sure how.

Comment: Not sure, If I understood your comment correctly, but please check my updated answer and see if that makes sense.